# When does $E[X] \leq E[Y]$ imply $E[X^2] \leq E[Y^2]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

> Assume $X, Y$ are two non-negative random variables. When does $E[X] \leq E[Y]$ imply $E[X^2] \leq E[Y^2]$?  Always?

I think the conclusion is not always true.

Comment: Just FYI, your counterexample does not involve nonnegative random variables.

Comment: Normal random variables take on negative values and thus are not a counter example to the question.

Comment: @angryavian Sorry, I corrected it.

Comment: @DilipSarwate You are right, sorry I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

As a counterexample, let $X=B(p)/p$ and $Y=B'(q)/q$, where $B,B'$ are iid Bernoulli with probability $p,q$. Then $E[X]=E[Y]=1$,
but $E[X^2]=1/p$ and $E[Y^2]=1/q$, which will violate your inequality when $p<q$.

There's a lot of conditions that would imply your inequality. For example in terms of second moments, $E[X^2]\leq E[Y]^2$ would imply $E[X^2]\leq E[Y^2]$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $Y=1$ and let $X$ be uniformly distributed on $[0, M]$, with $M \le 2$ so that $EX \le EY$.

Then $EX^2 = {M^3 \over 3}, E Y^2 = 1$ and $EX^2 \le EY^2$ **iff** $M \le \sqrt[3]{3} \approx 1.44 < 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $X,Y$ are non-negative, $E[X] \le E[Y] \iff E[X]^2 \le E[Y]^2$.  Meanwhile, you want:

$$ 0 \le E[Y^2] - E[X^2] \\ = (E[Y]^2 + Var(Y)) - (E[X]^2 + Var(X)) \\ = (E[Y]^2 - E[X]^2) + (Var(Y) - Var(X))$$

So, as Alex R. said, there are many conditions which would lead to what you want.  A particularly simple additional sufficient condition would be $Var(Y) \ge Var(X)$, but it is not necessary.  Another way to say this is that any counterexample must have $Var(Y) < Var(X)$ -- the counterexample of copper.hat exploited this.